# Vertical scrollbar not appearing on website

Tags: html, css, scroll

I can't figure out why the vertical scrollbar is not displaying on my website. It used to be working fine, but I had to re-upload the website just recently and afterwards the scrollbar is no longer working even though all the code should be exactly the same:

http://www.atnight.net.nz

This is the main body HTML from my layout.scss file

```html
html,
body {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 99%;
}

body {
  display: block;
  background: $dark-grey url('../img/backgrounds/broken_noise.png') repeat;
}

.row {
  @include col-container;
  margin: auto;
}

/*Dark Scrollbar */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: .85em;
    height: .85em;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: $grey-500;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 5em;
    background-color: $grey-900;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to a `class` on the `<body>` (from `_utilities.scss`):

```css
.nonscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```html
<body onload="init();" class="onePage nonscroll HomePage no-sidebar" dir="ltr">
```

Comment: Ah yup, that's it - thanks. However just realized that is meant to be there, as there is meant to be a page preloader (prevents page from scrolling while it preloads) but that isn't showing up anymore. So now need to figure out why the preloader isn't working as it should be...

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the webkit first before any styles before body styles